# Agregar datos serializados en un JTable en JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo este fragmento de codigo donde el if pregunta si no se escribrio en todos los JTextField y y si lo hace crea el archivo (el archivo guarda un arraylist).. ahora bien,mi duda viene de como hago para poder mostrar los datos del archivo en un JTable que esta en otra clase.

```
    if (nombre.getText().equals("") != (documento.getText().equals("")) != (apellido.getText()).equals("")) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "POR FAVOR LLENAR TODAS LAS CASILLAS ", "ERROR", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

    } else {
        lista.add(new Datos.Hotel(documento.getText(), nombre.getText(), apellido.getText(), habitacion.getText()));

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("L:\\final\\PruebaHotel.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(lista);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos guardados");
            oos.close();// cierra el archivo

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El archivo no existe " + e);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos de salida no son correctos " + ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Qué has intentado hacer? Porque el código mostrado no tiene NADA QUE VER con la pregunta en sí. Por favor, revisa el [help] y [ask].

Comment: Por cierto, tu código falla si no se rellena ninguno de los campos.

Comment: @SJuan76 cumple con su funcion el codigo, ese es el fragmento del archivo... mi duda yace en como puedo hacer para visualizar en una tabla el archivo serializado.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes leer el archivo, te recomiendo que revises si estas escribiendo el archivo por lineas o todo seguido dado que esta solucion es solo si los registros del archivo estan separados por salto de linea, dicho eso la solucion:

> Nota: este codigo lo e extraido de http://codigomaldito.blogspot.pe/2011/06/como-leer-un-archivo-de-texto-en-java.html

```
try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("LeerArchivo.java");
        DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
        String strLinea;
        while ((strLinea = buffer.readLine()) != null)   {
            System.out.println (strLinea);
        }
        entrada.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Si esta todo en una linea pero lo separas por comas o algo, solo cambia por `strLinea = buffer.readLine;` y luego haces uso de la funcion split para separarlo.

Luego pasas esos datos de linea a una lista de objetos.

y para mostrarlo en un jTable seria:

> Este si es de mi autoria XP

```
//Aqui estas sacando el modelo de tu jTable        
DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            //Esta es la lista de objetos que generaste a partir de tu archivo
            ArrayList<objeto_individual> lista;
            Object[] fila = new Object[modelo.getColumnCount()];
            for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
                //aqui vas seteando cada columna
                fila[0] = lista.get(i).get();
                fila[1] = lista.get(i).get();
                fila[2] = lista.get(i).get();

                modelo.addRow(fila);
            }
```